# How to show a drop down menu for the highlighted words

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

So in my code, the words are highlighted. In the highlighted words, I want to show a drop down menu which would do something like changing of color of the text. I was also wondering how to show dynamic words for each of the highlighted words. Those dynamic words would be received from an api. Anyway for now, even the static list of words are not showing in the drop down menu.

the sandbox for the code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-meninsky-tdqru

React code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import "./App.css";

const stripChars = word => word.replace(/[\W_]+/g, "");

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    text: "The gun is a dangerous weapon, don't kill anyone",
    highlight: ["gun", "kill"]
    // text: "",
    // highlight: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1ep1fh")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        let text = "";
        let highlight = [];
        for (const item of result) {
          text += item.text + "\n";
          highlight = [...highlight, ...item.highlight];
        }
        this.setState({
          text,
          highlight
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { text, highlight } = this.state;
    const words = text.split(" ");
    return (
      <div>
        {words.map((word, i) => (
          <span key={i}>
            <span
              id="new"
              className={
                highlight.includes(stripChars(word)) && "highlight dropbtn"
              }
              onClick="myFunction()"
            >
              {word}
            </span>
            &nbsp;
          </span>
        ))}
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#was">was</a>
          <a href="#were">were</a>
          <a href="#will">will</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

the javascript file

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches(".dropbtn")) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains("show")) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove("show");
      }
    }
  }
  if (event.target.tagName === "A") {
    var color;
    var _href = event.target.getAttribute("href");
    switch (_href) {
      case "#was":
        color = "green";
        break;
      case "#were":
        color = "Aqua";
        break;
      case "#will":
        color = "Magenta";
        break;
      default:
        color = "red";
    }
    document.getElementById("new").style.color = color;
  }
};
```

the css file

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
}
.highlight {
  background: red;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.dropbtn {
  color: white;

  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980b9;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: you have on the component `onClick="myFunction()"` . you are just passing a string to an event. Use `onClick={() => myFunction()}` . And move all the logic from script.js file inside the component. Or import it. But as you are doing it there is no way your component ' knows ' about the `script.js` file. So i suggest you either do all your logic inside the component. Or you export your functions ( maybe as static methods inside a class, rearrange them or just use `export const myFunction` ....etc ) and import them and call them in your component.

Comment: i used the scipt.js files in the index.html file under the public folder. doesn't that work?

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't refer an external function and do DOM manipulation in react to achieve this. you can just create a state variable and toggle it based on word clicked. Drop down display can be binded to same variable.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const stripChars = word => word.replace(/[\W_]+/g, "");

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    text: "The gun is a dangerous weapon, don't kill anyone",
    highlight: ["gun", "kill"],
    displayDrop: false
    // text: "",
    // highlight: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1ep1fh")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        let text = "";
        let highlight = [];
        for (const item of result) {
          text += item.text + "\n";
          highlight = [...highlight, ...item.highlight];
        }
        this.setState({
          text,
          highlight
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { text, highlight } = this.state;
    const words = text.split(" ");
    return (
      <div>
        {words.map((word, i) => (
          <span key={i}>
            <span
              id="new"
              className={
                highlight.includes(stripChars(word)) && "highlight dropbtn"
              }
              onClick={() => this.setState({ displayDrop: true })}
            >
              {word}
            </span>
            &nbsp;
          </span>
        ))}
        {this.state.displayDrop && (
          <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#was">was</a>
            <a href="#were">were</a>
            <a href="#will">will</a>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

// css: no need to add display: none

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
}
.highlight {
  background: red;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.dropbtn {
  color: white;

  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #2980b9;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

Above code will handle display of drop down. You can save the options too in state and change options based on element clicked in same way.

Comment: it is not working properly. you can still see in the codesandbox demo that the drop down menu appears and doesn't go away if we click on the background. also, i want the drop down menu to show just below the highlighted words but it is showing on the left side of the window

Comment: I have just added the code for displaying it, for hiding it again you need another onclick on topmost div which sets displayDrop to false. Also regarding positioning on drop down you need additional css.

Comment: I did add onClick={() => this.setState({ displayDrop: false })} on the topmost div but it isn't showing any drop down menu now